# RuntimeError: Unsupported: ONNX export of index_put in opset 9. Please try opset version 11

Tags: pytorch, torch, onnx

I was converting our custom Pytorch model to Trt and run it on a Jetson.
While converting pt to ONNX I am getting an error like:
RuntimeError: Unsupported: ONNX export of index_put in opset 9. Please try opset version 11.
reference:
https://github.com/onnx/onnx/issues/3057#issuecomment-707857945

I got this error while trying to run this code

```
import torch.onnx
# Standard ImageNet input - 3 channels, 224x224,
# values don't matter as we care about network structure.
# But they can also be real inputs.
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
# Invoke export
# torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "best.onnx")
```

I solve this error by adding this attribute  opset_version=11 in the function torch.onnx.export() as follow

```
import torch.onnx
# Standard ImageNet input - 3 channels, 224x224,
# values don't matter as we care about network structure.
# But they can also be real inputs.
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
# Invoke export
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "best.onnx", opset_version=11)
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve this error by adding this attribute opset_version=11 in the function torch.onnx.export() as follows

```
import torch.onnx
# Standard ImageNet input - 3 channels, 224x224,
# values don't matter as we care about network structure.
# But they can also be real inputs.
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
# Invoke export
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "best.onnx", opset_version=11)
```